# Understand the suspension (topology) and some Lie group examples

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, geometric-topology, morphism

Let $\Sigma$ denotes a [suspension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_(topology)) 
$$\Sigma X =S^1 \wedge X \equiv (S^1\times X)/(X\vee S^1)$$ 
where $\wedge$ and $\vee$ are the smash product and the wedge sum (one point union) of pointed topological spaces respectively.

I understand the [wedge sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_sum) is a "one-point union" of a family of topological spaces. But the suspension is harder to imagine.

(1) So what are the examples that we can identify the suspension $\Sigma X$ for
(special) unitary groups and (special) orthogonal groups?

- $\Sigma X = \Sigma SU(n)=?$
- $\Sigma X = \Sigma U(n)=?$
- $\Sigma X = \Sigma SO(n)=?$
- $\Sigma X = \Sigma O(n)=?$

(2) What is the good way to understand intuitively the suspension (topology) in terms of simple pictures?

Comment: This isn't a real answer, but in general you shouldn't expect the suspension to be recognizable as something more "common."  (The glaring exceptions are the spheres.)

Comment: Isn't the picture coming from the definition - taking a product and collapse a wedge - intuitive enough? At least it gives a nice intuition why $\Sigma S^n=S^{n+1}$ to me.

Comment: @cjackal, thanks, I mean for the more general topological spaces.

Comment: Then I guess it depends strongly on your understanding of the base space. BTW, do you have a good description of $O(n)$ as a topological space? Unless there may not exist a good answer to its suspension.

Comment: @cjackal, I ask an elementary one that maybe you already knew the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884901

Answer (score 2):

As Randall said in his comment, suspensions of "well-known spaces" in general do not produce something common. But you can imagine how it looks like via the picture in your question [The suspension (topology) and elementary examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2884901)  - provided you can imagine how spaces like $SU(n)$ look like ;-)

As far as I know, the suspensions in your examples are no spaces denoted by a "standard name".

I guess your interest in suspensions comes from algebraic topology, at least I do not know many other places where there are relevant. In this context it suffices to consider *homotopy types* of spaces. As I mentioned in my answer to your other question, you may sometimes find something "more common" homotopy equivalent to a suspension.

Moreover, for any pointed space $(X,x_0)$ with a non-degenerate basepoint the reduced suspension $\Sigma (X,x_0)$ has the same homotopy type as the unreduced suspension $S X$ (which is easier to imagine). Examples for such spaces are all manifolds, CW-complexes and polyhedra.

Finally it is remarkable that sometimes suspensions of "exotic spaces" yield well-known spaces (that is, you get a sort of *improvement*). See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_suspension_theorem.

Comment: thanks +1, this is helpful