# Understanding De/Suspension $\Sigma^{-1}(\Sigma{X})\neq X$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology, morphism

The question is about understanding suspension and [desuspension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desuspension), see also [a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2884901/79069).

> Question: How do we define desuspension exactly? (Please see the comments below, people complain about the meanings of desuspension in Wikipedia is useless).
>
> Are we able to have the desuspension acting on the topological space as the suspension does? Or do we only have the desuspension act on the spectra but not the space?

[It is said that in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desuspension):

$$\Sigma^{-1}(\Sigma{X})\neq X,$$

> 1. What is the intuitive explanation?
> 2. What are some examples with $\Sigma^{-1}(\Sigma{X})= X,$
>    and counter examples $\Sigma^{-1}(\Sigma{X})\neq X$?

Naively, I thought that for $X=S^1$

$$\Sigma^n{X}=S^{n+1},$$

while

$$\Sigma^{-n}{S^{n+1}}=S^{1},$$
is this still correct?

Note add: The desuspension is arguably firstly introduced in the cited text mentioned in [H. R. Margolis (1983). Spectra and the Steenrod Algebra. North-Holland. p. 454.](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT9580/v17/documents/margolisspectra.pdf)

Comment: What is the definition of desuspention. The link you have sited doesn't provide any good explanation.

Comment: This is a possible Ref: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~kwickelgren3/8803_Stable/L6_Suspension_is_equivalence.pdf -- I am also trying to get a clarification from any expert here.

Comment: Desuspension is for spectra, not spaces.

Comment: thanks, this rings the bell. However, in the note above, it says "Let $Σ^{−1}E$ be the CW spectrum with spaces $(Σ^{−1}E)_n = E_{n−1}$."

Comment: desuspension is an operation inverse to suspension

Comment: Dear all, I don't understand why the question is put on hold - I provide the information that one can find on the website.

Comment: I added the original Refs.

Comment: That wikipedia article is just awful, I would recommend that you ignore it.

Comment: The wikipedia page is saying nothing. Since you are asking about it, could you explain the definition of desuspension in your own language?

Comment: Dear Cave "desuspension is an operation inverse to suspension" This is all I know. I provide the relations I suppose them to be correct and ask about them. You can say that I am just trying to get an understanding of desuspension, as the title suggested. I dont see why I cannot ask these basic things - since everyone here who commented did not give any better answer, except this one "Desuspension is for spectra."

Comment: I'm actually the one voting to reopen, but "unclear what you're asking" seems not too unjustified. Let me infer from what you said that you do not know the precise definition of desuspension when posting this question. So the first question you should have asked is, "What does this wikipedia page mean? How do we define desuspension exactly?". None of these are shown in your question. Instead, it is worded like you've already been clear what desuspension is, and is merely asking for "intuition" and "examples". (cont)

Comment: thanks. p.s. desuspension is used in the ref given in eq.(7.9) in D Campbell's 1708.04264 and the related calculation discussed in https://mathoverflow.net/q/257717/27004

Comment: thanks,  Cave Johnson, I will follow your suggestion.

Comment: see the new edit